# flex lowercase to uppercase issue

Tags: string, apache-flex, air, uppercase

I got one problem. I called one image from server. example: "www.sample.com/images/image1.jpg"
But if someone changed the name to uppercase like IMAGE1.jpg. Flex doesn't display image.

solution plz?

Comment: Where did someone changed the name? Has the path of the image changed or you try to request "www.sample.com/images/image1.jpg" by the address "www.sample.com/images/IMAGE1.jpg"?

Comment: Actually we are e-CD rom publisher. Our client wants to maintain same structure for Every project. Client will put next project files in server with same name, but sometime the name wll be in uppercase or lowercase. We should not rename it without their permission.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a web server that does not requre case sensitive paths, like Microsoft's Internet Information Services.

Another option is to limit access to your server so that people cannot change the names of files.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got only two possible spelling for each name ("image1.jpg" and "IMAGE1.jpg") you can apply a dirty hack. Listen to `Image`'s error events ([ioError](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html#event%3aioError) and [securityError](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html#event%3asecurityError)) and after one fail try to load image by another path.